# Running laravel illuminate database transactions outside of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
require dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/config.php';

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

$dbc = new DB;

$dbc->addConnection(array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => DB_NAME,
    'username'  => DB_USER,
    'password'  => DB_PASSWORD,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
));

$dbc->setAsGlobal();
$dbc->bootEloquent();
```

$dbc->beginTransaction();

Gives me this error,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Capsule\\Manager::beginTransaction()
```

Can anyone provide me with some help as to how to use capsule and database transactions outside of laravel. I can't find anything that would suggest this doesnt work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get a connection instance to work with any database related methods (including `beginTransaction`). The class that implements them is `Illuminate\Database\Connection`. This means you need to get the connection instance from the manager and work with that:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

$capsule = new DB;

$capsule->addConnection(array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => DB_NAME,
    'username'  => DB_USER,
    'password'  => DB_PASSWORD,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
));

$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();

$connection = $capsule->getConnection();
$connection->beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that transaction work only for InnoDB, they won't work for MyISAM